# How to create a factory that behaves like a stream object

Tags: c++, stream, factory

I'm trying to create a factory class that can be read as if it is a stream object (sstream seems the most similar, but I could be wrong), be able to provide a predetermined amount of values and then stop (fail state, eof), AND be reference-compatible with cin.  I want to avoid using additional libraries like boost.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Factory : public std::stringstream {
    int count;
public:
    Factory() : count{ 0 } {}
    Factory & operator>>(int &x) {
        if (count < 2)
            x = count++;
        else
            this->setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    Factory f;
    char choice;
    std::cout << "Read from (c)in or (f)actory? ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::istream &ss = (choice == 'f') ? f : std::cin;
    while (ss >> a)
        std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When 'f' is input, nothing is read.  If I change the while loop to read directly from f instead of ss, it works as expected (reads 0, 1, and stops).

Comment: You mean something like a static instance behaving like `std::cin`? That's not really a _Factory_. Also you usually shouldn't inherit from classes provided by the c++ standard library, rather wrap them and use it as a member.

Comment: Not really a static instance.  If I can get this initial part working, I want to have the factory initialized with how much output to produce and a random seed, use an mt19937 object to generate the output, etc.  If I don't inherit from something compatible with cin, I can't have a reference that refers to either cin or the factory object.

Comment: You should add another level of indirection and call something like `f.create_my_stream()` which returns an instance of a `std::istream` compatible class.

Comment: As stated above, I want something that is compatible with istream, so that I can choose at runtime whether to read from cin or the factory object.  It doesn't have to be stringstream, if there's a better choice.

Comment: @Twist Your type does not provide the interface for an `std::istream`, so it is a design error to try to pass it off as one. One problem is that an `istream` can be read as many types, not just the `int` implementation you provide.

Comment: True about the limited types; I intend to add char, string, and maybe a few other types once the darn thing works.  The only holdup right now is why does the while loop immediately end when I use the reference, but works fine when I use "while (f >> a)".

Comment: You need to decide what exactly is part of the desired shared interface between your `Factory` class and `std::istream`. If `Factory` is intended to act like a sequence of characters which can be interpreted as integers, strings, or other types then it would be correct to derive it from `std::istream` but with a custom `std::streambuf` type. If it's just a sequence of integer *values* then the correct abstraction would be a type-erased iterator to a sequence of `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

apart of the healthy criticism in the comments, let's consider what happens here:

```
std::istream &ss = (choice == 'f') ? f : std::cin;
while (ss >> a)
```

`istreame` reference `ss` is calling `operator>>(int &)` (ADL aside). Thus, even if `ss` is pointing to your `Factory` class (which is idiomatically not a factory), it still will be calling its base operator, hence choice `f` never works.

If you wanted to achieve what you intended, then the `operator>>` must have been defined polymorphic (declared as `virtual`) in the base class. But it's not.

Thus your approach fails. If you wanted to achieve demultiplexing of your class (acting as a stream) and other `std::istream` based (just for your case), then the approach should have been redesigned into something like following:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Factory {
    int count;
    std::istream * is_ptr;
    static std::stringstream dummy;
public:
    Factory(std::istream &is = dummy): count{0}, is_ptr(&is) {}
    operator bool(void) { return count < 5; }
    Factory & operator>>(int &x) { 
        if(is_ptr == &dummy)                   // it's me being called
         { x = count++; return *this; }
        *is_ptr >> x;                          // otherwise, calling a proxy 
        return *this;
    }
};
std::stringstream Factory::dummy;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    Factory f, c(std::cin);
    char choice;
    std::cout << "Read from (c)in or (f)actory?\n";
    std::cin >> choice;
    //choice = 'f';
    Factory &ss = (choice == 'f') ? f : c;
    while (ss >> a)
        std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs with choice 'f':

```
Read from (c)in or (f)actory?
f
a = 0
a = 1
a = 2
a = 3
bash $
```

Outputs with choice 'c':

```
Read from (c)in or (f)actory?
c
123
a = 123
098765
a = 98765
^C
bash $
```